# Как определить размеры экранов андроид на kivy

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, dpi

Можете помочь.

Мне нужно, чтобы python Kivy определя длинну и высоту дисплея телефона для адаптпции приложений,т.к. пропорции извесны.

Такое можно как-то сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**kivy.core.window.Window**

Абстрактный виджет окна для любой реализации окна.

Параметры конструктора:

- width: int *— ширина окна*
- height: int *— высота окна*
- minimum_width: *int — минимальная ширина окна*
- minimum_height: *int — минимальная высота окна*

**dpi()** — Вернуть разрешение экрана. Если реализация не поддерживает поиск DPI, она просто вернет 96. *(Это значение не является кросс-платформенным. Используйте kivy.base.EventLoop.dpi вместо этого)*

Comment: Огромное спасибо, но мне нужны значения высоты и длинны дисплея, к примеру 480x800 (чтоб программа могла их определять и их можно было использовать)

Comment: @Lev145, ну так на мобильном телефоне корневое окно и так на весь дисплей. Размеры совпадают